# Local Search for Specific Stores

Tags: api, search-engine, local, foursquare, google-places-api

What is the best API or resource to use if I want to search locally for stores but limit it to specific chains?

i.e. I want to search for local big box stores but only come up with results that include Target, Walmart and Best Buy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Foursquare [venue search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) API to search for venues in a nearby are with a certain name. Just provide the lat/long of the area you want to search in, and the name in the `query` parameter.